# Return newest files for each folder in a directory tree

Tags: python

I have several text files located in different folders.

```
Southwest (folder)
     Texas (folder)
        Houston (folder)
           11-18-2018 (folder)
               Houston.txt (date modified 11-18-2018)
           11-11-2018 (folder)
               Houston.txt (date modified 11-11-2018)

        Austin (folder)
           11-18-2018 (folder)
               Austin.txt (date modified 11-18-2018)
           11-11-2018 (folder)
               Austin.txt (date modified 11-11-2018)

Southern_Pacific (folder)
     California
        San-Diego (folder)
           11-18-2018 (folder)
               San_Diego.txt (date modified 11-18-2018)
           11-11-2018 (folder)
               San_Diego.txt (date modified 11-11-2018)

        Los_Angeles (folder)
           11-18-2018 (folder)
               Los_Angeles.txt (date modified 11-18-2018)
           11-11-2018 (folder)
               Los_Angeles.txt (date modified 11-11-2018)


 and so on with other different regions in US.
```

Goal: I need to grab all the newest files for each folder based on the cities they reside. So the return value would be something like:

```
C:\Southwest\Texas\Houston\11-18-2018\Houston.txt
C:\Southwest\Texas\Austin\11-18-2018\Austin.txt
C:\Southern_Pacific\California\San_Diego\11-18-2018\San_Diego.txt
C:\Southern_Pacific\California\Los_Angeles\11-18-2018\Los_Angeles.txt
```

I will then use the return values as path to open the files and feed through another function that I have built. But at the moment the other function only works when the files reside in the same folder where I run the script or I specifically point it to sub folder - not the entire tree.

So at this point I need to be able to go through each folder, grab the newest file for each city, return the value as path to the file.

I'm new to python or scripting in general. A helping hand would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: First look at the os.walk() method.

Comment: Is it always true, that the folder name is the date of modification? If so and you could change its naming format from "Month-Day-Year" to "Year-Month-Day", then the last folder in alphabetical order is always the newest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my solution for you:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

def getNewestFiles(startpath):
    path = ""
    currTime = 0
    maxTime = 0
    resultPath = ""

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(startpath): #search from start to all folders and files
        maxTime = 0
        resultPath = ""

        for f in files:
            path = root+"\\"+f
            currTime = os.path.getmtime(path) #get time of file
            if(currTime > maxTime): #compare time with other files
                maxTime = currTime
                resultPath = path   #take the largest number

        if(resultPath != ""):
            print('{} : {}'.format(resultPath, datetime.fromtimestamp(float(os.path.getmtime(resultPath))).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

You have to choose your startpath and then you get all newest files in all directories

Answer (score 0):

Use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20walk#os.walk) to navigate the directory structure and [os.path.getmtime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getmtime) to determine the modification time for each file.

For comparing the times, I recommend using the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#module-datetime) module.